# jquery selector does not work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I have used a template on my web site. Although I have the `<div class="carousel slide"`, the jquery selector `$(".carousel")` does not work. What is the problem with this code? Is it a special flag for jquery?

Here is the web site: rezayad.org

Comment: And what are you trying do with that select? bind event?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your JQuery setup. $("*anything*") returns `null`

Comment: yes @Jonathan and i don't know why it happens!

Comment: Show code where you try to use: $(".carousel") !!!

Comment: @roasted it returns null for everything!

Comment: I asked you to show us your code where you are trying to use it!

Comment: i put that code @roasted

Comment: So you don't have anywhere `$(".carousel")` in your code? I was not asking you to put all your site code here, just the relevant part

Comment: @roasted you can use firebug console to test the selector. I got the answer thanks to Jonathan

Comment: @roasted you may remove the down-vote, because I was considering you to use the firebug selector!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have JQuery noConflict running, but this works:

```
jQuery('.carousel')
```